# Undefined symbol "tbb internal Allocate" when loading shared library

Tags: c++, c, linux, runtime-error, tbb

some people using my shared library have problems loading it.
I already told them to install "gcc-libs" as stated [here](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/i686/intel-tbb/).

I also told them to compile the shared library themselves, but without luck.

Are there other solutions to this problem?

This is a log file from the program which tries to load the plugin on CentOS6:

```
[23:16:57]   Failed (plugins/RouteConnectorPlugin.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3tbb8internal12NFS_AllocateEjjPv)
[23:16:57]  Loading plugin failed: RouteConnectorPlugin.so
```

The program is open source and located [here](https://gpb.googlecode.com/files/RouteConnectorPlugin_182b.zip), it's written in a mix of C and C++ (the program is compiled for x86 only).

Comment: @KillianDS you mean the \libs\ from the .tgz?
And I told them to install GCC-libs but it seems not to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your shared library depends on another shared library you should link against it. Then when your library is linked into some other executable/shared library that dependency will be automatically loaded and users don't need to explicitly link against that dependency.

The undefined symbol is

```
$ c++filt _ZN3tbb8internal12NFS_AllocateEjjPv
tbb::internal::NFS_Allocate(unsigned int, unsigned int, void*)
```

which might come from the intel-tbb library you mentioned. Since this a dependency of your code users expect you to properly declare that dependency by linking it into your library.

See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892328/how-to-link-a-so-file-to-a-so-file) on how to do this with with GCC.