# how to link a .so file to a .so file

Tags: c, linux, dll, linker, shared-libraries

I am creating a .so file with a C code. I need to link some other .so files to the .so file am creating. how to do it?

I tried this  `-L{path to file containing library} -l${library name}` is it right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your library file is called `/path/to/libfile.so`, then typically you'd need to specify the following arguments to the linker:

```
-L/path/to -lfile
```

Note that we only include the directory in `-L`, and omit both the `lib` prefix and the `.so` suffix from `-l`.

Comment: Thanks,I did the same as u said. But am facing some issues. I need to call a webservice from a SASL mechanism. I used axis C++ and created stub files and wrote a sample code to call a webservice. Now I need to integrate Axis c++ code into the SASL plugin Mechanism ( say plain.c). here, I added the .h files and also the .so files in the make file. I got a .so file as a result. But the .so file is not working as expected. If I add the resultant .so and give a command "sasl2-shared-mechlist" I will get the list of mechanisms available. But after my changes am not getting the listed mechanisms.

Comment: @2vision2 "is not working as expected" is not a problem description that anyone can help you with. Perhaps if you describe the problem in a bit more detail someone will be able to help, but as written, you're expecting people to use their crystal ball to know the issue (and almost everyone's crystal ball seems broken these days).

Comment: @mah thanks and its valid. After adding the .so file (generated form plain.c and Axis C++ code ) into /lib64 directory. If I give the command "Shared-mech-lists" I can see the list of mechanisms available. If I add the Axis C++ code into the plain.c from which the .so is generated, I am not getting the list of mechanisms.